# Unable to find path for sdk

Tags: android-studio, sdk

During starting, Android Studio is asking path for SDK. I am not able to locate the same after several answers on internet. Also, I have re-installed Android Studio million of times but the same issue is persisting. Kindly resolve.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Please provide the *exact* text of the error message since it will help others when searching for answers. Also, take the time to list all the steps that have been tried to prevent folks making redundant suggestions. Lastly, please show the environment variables that you have set. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Comment: I expect someone out of these android experts to reply to such petty issues. I have been trying all the solution given in the portal but none of them seems to make sense. Please help in resolving the issue. There is no SDK folder anywhere in my PC, let it be normal or hidden folder, AppData or Local folder or Android folder. I have been struggling over this since weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Answers mentioned at several other threads in Stack overflow did not solve my issue of Android Studio. To resolve, I had to go back to the Android Studio download page. Bottom of the page contains download link to "sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip". Just downloaded the same and extracted to a suitable location. Now mentioned the path to this folder in Android Studio. It then automatically installed the suitable tools for Android Studio to work.